# COCOS2D best way to change level when score has been reached

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have some difficulties making the level change only once when the player has reach a certain score during the game. It keeps changing every time the players gets a new score which is very annoying.

```
//Change the level
        if(score >= 600){

                level = level+1;
                [levellabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",level]];
                id ScaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scale:14.0 ];
                id ScaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scale:1.0 ];
                [levellabel runAction:[CCSequence actions:ScaleUp, ScaleDown, nil] ];
        }
```

I also tried with setting the if statement to if(score >= 600 && score<1000) and then use a new if statement telling it to change the level once again when the score >=2000 but if I do that nothing seems to happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following if you have a control over the levels and a max cap on the levels..

```
-(void)addLevel
    {
    level = level+1;
                    [levellabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",level]];
                    id ScaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scale:14.0 ];
                    id ScaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scale:1.0 ];
                    [levellabel runAction:[CCSequence actions:ScaleUp, ScaleDown, nil] ];
    }
    -(void)newScore
    {  
       int target = 0;
       switch(level):
       {
       case 1:
          target = 600;
       break;
       case 2:
          target = 1000;
       break;
       case 3:
           target = 2000;
       break;
       }

       if(score>=target)
       [self addLevel];
    }
```

if its infinite and follows a standard formula, in this example, increase level for every 1000 score, it should be:

```
-(void)addScore
{
   int nxtLvl = level +1;

   if(score>=1000*nxtLvl)
   [self addLevel];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I used the second choice and it worked fine :D

Comment: so you have a custom score for each level? Not a "standard" formula?

Comment: To be honest... I haven't decided yet. so far I'm just changing level on every 10 000 points.